# Creating Instance of a Class using reflection,whose parameters are injected by autofac

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, autofac, autofac-module

I am creating some WCF services in which I am using Autofac as the IOC.
Now I need to create an instance of one of the classes using reflection whose 
parameters are injected by Autofac.
But when I use Activator.CreateInstance its giving exception as the constructor is not there.After I add a parameter less constructor, the paramters passed in the constructor which is supposed to be instantiated by Autofac is not getting instantiated.Anyone please help me in fixing this

Comment: Why do you have to create instance of class using reflection ? Could you share some code ?

Comment: Snippet please. Activator.CreateInstance doesn't know nothing about autofac (as i know) - provide your code sample (we should see .ctor sygnatures of class and Activator.CreateInstance call and how it's binded to autofac